# Alias Classes in Java

Tags: java, class

I have a series of auto generated classes that result in the same class name. The solution to this was to separate the classes into different packages. When creating functions in another class that uses multiple auto generated classes my code results in something like the following to avoid class and package collision issues.

```
... Other methods with similar functionality that reference a 
        different auto generated class.    

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public FutureTask<com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.
GetCommandsResponse.ObjectClass> SendLogEntryEventAsync(final 
        com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsRequest 
        request)
{
    FutureTask<com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsResponse.
    ObjectClass> futureTask;

    Callable<com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsResponse.
    ObjectClass> call = new Callable<com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.
    GetCommandsResponse.ObjectClass>()
    {
        public com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.GetCommandsResponse.
    ObjectClass call() throws ResponseException
        {
            return SendGetCommandRequest(request);
        }
    };

    futureTask = new FutureTask<com.CompanyName.ProductName.SDK.Device.
            GetCommandsResponse.ObjectClass>(call);

    return futureTask;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
... More methods with similar functionality that reference a 
        different auto generated class.    

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This is not a problem for me as a programmer, as I don't mind typing out the packages when casting or declaring types.

What concerns me is, that because this code is intended to be part of an SDK and will be distributed to third party developers, these long class names will become irritating; and at worst developers will refuse to use the SDK due to hassle.

Is it possible to create wrapper classes that alias these auto-generated classes, so the names are unique, easy to understand, caste, and declare?

If so how would I do this?

Comment: You could always use Subclassing. Make subclasses that extend the complicated path Classes, then put them into the same package with distinct easy alias names.

Comment: Why not to use what they call an Adapter pattern?

Comment: I have not heard of an Adapter pattern, or Facade before. I will look into it.

Comment: An API should be defined with interfaces and a minimum of concrete classes.

Comment: @greedybuddha "Favor composition over inheritance." It is better to have decorator classes that contain instances of the classes with large names and that implement the same interfaces as those classes.

Comment: @gparyani I disagree here. What he ideally wants to do is give them the classes themselves, which would include methods **and** variables.  The only way to approximate that here is with subclassing. The composition approach loses out on class internals.